# Error al correr app para IOS en xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode

Como puedo resolver este tipo de error, al momento de correr una app par IOS en xcode 9.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Actualiza tu xcode,el error es que ese framework fue compilado con swift 4 mientras que estás intentando compilar con swift 3, sólo actuliza el xcode... o busca el equivalente a ese framework para tu versión de swift.

Answer (score 1):

Tu framework llamado **Crypto** (`Crypto.framework`) actualemente está compilado con Swift 3, y estás usando Swift 4 (eso parece).

Ayudaría mucho que compartieras tu **Cartfile** para ver que librería `Crypto` estás usando, ya que he visto varias opciones y no se cuál estás usando:

1. https://github.com/soffes/Crypto (soporta Swift 4 a partir de la version **0.5.4**)
2. https://github.com/alexaubry/Crypto
3. u otra ...

Revisa la documentación y confirma que tu librería está soportando Swift 4.

Comment: Si estimado estoy utilizando estas librerias:# MD5
github "soffes/CommonCrypto"
github "soffes/Crypto"

Comment: Entonces tu `Cartfile` deberia tener en la dependencia algo como `github "soffes/Crypto" ~> 0.5.4` (si efectivamente estás usando Swift 4).